# Linux commands explanation

Tags: linux, bash

I can't find this in the  linux --help. 
may you please tell me what theses commands are dowing

```
NAME=gs://toto-titi-dfs-dfe-gfd-zed/
```

then the ambiguous commands are :

```
NAME="${NAME//\\/\\\\}"
NAME="${NAME//\//\\/}"
```

then we have these two commands:

```
sudo sed -i "s/spark\.eventLog\.dir.*/spark\.eventLog\.dir $NAME/g" /usr/lib/spark/conf/spark-defaults.conf
sudo sed -i "s/spark\.history\.fs\.logDirectory.*/spark\.history\.fs\.logDirectory $NAME/g" /usr/lib/spark/conf/spark-defaults.conf
```

Which I can't understand too

Any help with this please

Thanks a lot

Comment: The intention is to escape any forward slashes in the variable. Unescaped slashes would break the sed `s///` command. I have advocated for this technique here on SO.

Comment: The explanations for the 1st part of your question can be found [here](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html) under the section 'Substring Replacement'

Comment: you can also see for yourself the value/power of `NAME="${NAME//\\/\\\\}"` by building up some debugging statements, like `echo "NAME=xx${NAME}xx"; NAME="${NAME//\\/\\\\}"; echo "NAME=xx${NAME}xx"; .....`. Good luck.

Comment: AND such requests for explanations are more appropriate to https://superuser.com . Please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: Seems *much* cleaner to use `sed 's@...@...@` than to try to sanitize the string.  You still may need to sanitize the string to escape `@` characters, but if that's really an issue you shouldn't be doing this is the shell.  Pick a suitable delimiter.

Comment: @WilliamPursell if the value of `NAME` can contain backslashes, `NAME="${NAME//\\/\\\\}"` would still be necessary though

Comment: True, but if a path can contain backslashes, then there are bigger issues that must be addressed. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Set the variable `NAME` to the string `gs://toto-titi-dfs-dfe-gfd-zed/`
2. Swap out all instances of `\` with `\\` in that variable using `NAME="${NAME//\\/\\\\}"` Read about [Shell Parameter Expansion here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) specifically the section labelled *${parameter/pattern/string}*.
3. Swap out all instaces of `/` with `\/` in the `NAME` variable using `AME="${NAME//\//\\/}"`. These two steps are being performed to escape out the `/` and `\` in the `NAME` variable so that `sed` doesn't choke.
4. In file `/usr/lib/spark/conf/spark-defaults.conf` replace out matches of `spark.eventLog.dir.*` with `spark.eventLog.dir $NAME`
5. In file `/usr/lib/spark/conf/spark-defaults.conf` replace out matches of `spark.history.fs.logDirectory.*` with `spark.history.fs.logDirectory $NAME`